# Spring SecurityXML. http tag inheritance

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a `security-spring.xml` with some general rules applied for many urls and I want to make an exception for one specific url that also matches that pattern. Can I do it without copying the complete `<http>` tag?

What I tried is this:

```
<beans ...>

    <http pattern="/a/b" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" >
        <csrf disabled="true"/><!-- An exception I want to add -->
    </http>

    <http pattern="/a/**" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" ...someproperties >
         <!-- General config for many urls -->
    </http>

</beans>
```

Accessing `/a/b` without csrf token works but looks like it doesn't inherit any config properties from the `/a/**` pattern.

Is that how it's supposed to be (each http is independent) or is there a way to "append" this exception to `/a/b` and inherit the rest from the `/a/**`?

Spring-security version: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<csrf>` configuration element is a sub-element of the main container element for security configuration, i.e. the `<http>` element.

So yes, if you would like to have the *Corss-site Request Forgery* disabled / enabled for a configured sub-url, you have to duplicate all the necessary configuration elements.

One particular solution to avoid duplication would be to opt for a *Java*-based configuration.